# Proj4 string for Hobo–Dyer projection?

Tags: proj

I was fortunate to find an SVG of this projection at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4476487/

However, there appears to be little reference to this projection outside of wikipedia. Does anybody know what the Proj4 string would be?

Comment: Wikipedia says it's a cylindrical equal with standard parallels at +/-37.5.

Comment: So something like: +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=37.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs